# Ajax client connecting to a Django (cross domain) works only with JSONP

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

We have a Django application running in tomcat with Basic Authentication.
I want to make cross domain request but only with $.ajax({...dataType: 'JSONP',...}) it works. dataType: JSON doesnt work. Does that mean the server doesnt have CORS enabled. Any tips or pointers to enable CORS in Django

Answer (score 0):

JSONP was made to make cross-domain requests. The main drawback to using it is that you can only do GET requests with it. If you only need to do GET requests then it should probably serve your purpose to keep using JSONP.

To enable CORS in django, you can use the `django-cors-header` app (a guide on that [here](https://github.com/crs4/ome_seadragon/wiki/Enable-Django-CORS-(Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing)-Headers-configuration)).